# How to use array filter based on index without using element callback in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

I got the below error in tslint.

[image]
 So is there any way to use filter based on array index without using element callback or any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `_` instead of `x`. `_` means you don't need / care about this value.